What's the correct way to forward stdout of a subprocess to the stdout of the current process in Rust?
I'm having a difficulty figuring out how to forward stdout of a command to the current process's stdout. What I currently have is this, but it slurps in all of the content of stdout, and doesn't account for processes writing to stdout in chunks before the process terminates:
let output = Command::new(cmd)
 .args(args)
 .output()
 .expect("Error reading process stdout");

print!(
  "{}",
  String::from_utf8(output.stdout).expect("Invalid output")
);

Is there a way to read this output incrementally and print chunks as they come?

Just use spawn() instead of output(). It will redirect the standard streams (stdin, stdout and stderr) to the parent process.
